# Visual Studio c++ how to add version info read from .rc or .h to targetname?

Tags: c++, properties, visual-studio-2013, build, filenames

Is it possible to automatically read version data (major/minor/revision) from a resource script file (.rc) or an include file (.h) and add it to $(TargetName) / OUTPUT FILE property so that the resulting built executable contains the version info in its name?

The version data is incrementally generated at each build, so the build script will have to resolve the version contents and use it to name the output file.

Comment: I am sorry as I didn't fully explain: the version data is incrementally generated at each build. Thus, it has to be done automatically, as part of the build script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Property Macros.  So if you were to bring up Property Manager (View > Property Manager) and right-click a configuration and choose Add New Property Sheet... then edit that property sheet by right-clicking on it and choosing properties.  Then under Common Properties and then User Macros make a new macro with the Add Macro button.

Say you called it Version with value 1.0.0 then you can OK out of the dialogs and go to the project properties and for the Target Name have it be $(ProjectName)_$(Version) and build your project and that will work.

The property sheet is plain text so your automated script could edit this file on each build.  You might need to delete a hidden file, the .suo file, if VS isn't picking up the changes from one build to the next.

Though if I may suggest a few other approaches.

- Perhaps your build script could rename the output file?
- Within VS you could have a post-build step that can read the version information from the executable and rename the file.  Here is a function call that can be used to read the version information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  It could be done all from a script instead.
- Try CMake.  CMake allows you to generate your VS solution and project files and can do some extraordinary things.

Hope that was helpful!

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to avoid doing it from an external tool since I thought the build properties would be a straight forward way, but I guess renaming the file is much simpler. And I'll definitely take a look on CMake - thanks for the tip too.

Comment: Just in case some people are having trouble finding **Property Manager** for me it was under View > Other Windows > Property Manager.